# Matplotlib dynamic plot Autoscale not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, plot, dynamic

I am using FuncAnimation and want to autoscale my y-axis, but it isn't working.

Below is the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import random

fig = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

if(1):
    ax2.set_facecolor('midnightblue')
    ax2.grid(True,linewidth=0.2)
    ax2.set_xlabel("Range(meters)")
    ax2.set_ylabel("Signal Strength")
    ax2.set_xlim([0,20])
    # ax2.set_ylim([15000,1800000])
    ax2.autoscale(enable=True, axis='y')
    # ax2.set_ylim([0,5800])
    ax2.set_title("Range profile", color='black')
    ax2.xaxis.label.set_color('black')       
    ax2.yaxis.label.set_color('black')          
    ax2.tick_params(axis='x', colors='black') 
    ax2.tick_params(axis='y', colors='black')
    # print(y1)
    a2, = ax2.plot([], [],c='red',alpha=1,label="Range Profile")


def func_init():
    a2.set_data([],[])

def update(i):

    if(1):
                y1 = np.random.randint(1005,1000000, (1,64))
                x1 = np.linspace(0,63,64)
                x1 = x1/10
               
                a2.set_data(x1,y1)

    return a2,


ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, init_func = func_init, interval=270, blit=True, save_count=0, cache_frame_data=False)

plt.show()
```

When I hardcode the axis limits, it works fine...

What is the solution?................................................